# Centering an image vertically inside an anchor tag in a flex item

Tags: css, html, flexbox

I am trying to center images inside cells of a flex layout with flex-direction set to row, with the height of each cell in a row equal to the maximum of height of the images of that row.

The other smaller images of the row should be centered with respect to height.

Tried centering with vertical align and margins, does not seem to work.

```js
function getRandomSize(min, max) {
 return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
var width = getRandomSize(200, 400);
var height =  getRandomSize(200, 400);
$('#photos').append('<a style="display:inline-block" href="http://www.google.com" ><img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/'+width+'/'+height+'/cats" alt="pretty kitty"></a>');
}
```

```css
        #photos{
            display: flex; /* Initializing a flexbox formatting context */
            flex-flow : row wrap ;/*flex-direction and flex-wrap*/
        }

        #photos a:nth-child(odd){
            flex : 0 0 20%;
            background-color: aqua;
            border:1px solid black;
            height:auto;
        }

        #photos a:nth-child(even){
            flex : 0 0 20%;
            background-color: red;
            border:1px solid yellow;
            height:auto;
        }



        #photos img{
            width : 100%;
            padding: auto;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="photos">
    </div>
```

Here is a link to jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/k3gbquda/

Is this possible? Can somebody suggest a solution?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"A" element should be a nested flexbox not an inline block.

```
    #photos {
        display: flex; /* Initializing a flexbox formatting context */
        flex-flow: row wrap ;/*flex-direction and flex-wrap*/
    }

    #photos a {
        flex : 0 0 20%;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }

    #photos a:nth-child(odd) {
        background-color: aqua;
        border:1px solid black;
    }

    #photos a:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: red;
        border:1px solid yellow;
    }

    #photos img {
        width : 100%;
        height: auto;
        display: block;
    }
```

See modified fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1wpgo45t/7/

Answer (score 0):

There is a flexbox property called align-items which is exactly what you're looking for.

`align-items: center;`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#photos a:nth-child(odd){
        flex : 0 0 20%;
        background-color: aqua;
        border:1px solid black;
        height:auto;
        margin:auto;
}
```